# How to get the parent array indside the filter [Flex]?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have the code as following

```
var ar:Array = ["Joe","Bob","Curl","Curl"];
var distinctData = ar.filter(function(itm, i){
    return ar.indexOf(itm)== i; 
});
```

The question is how can I get the parent array **ar** inside the filter function? I tried **this** keyword but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument of [`filter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter()) can be used to provide a value for `this` within the callback. In your case that means you can do:

```
ar.filter(function(itm, i) {
    return this.indexOf(itm) === i;
}, ar);
```

Comment: Your ActionScript-3 tag score just hit 1,000 - there's a gold badge headed your way, I think.

Comment: @JasonSturges I suspect I have you to thank for that :-)